# Can't get JSON to render correctly in dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm trying to take JSON from a PHP file and use it to populate a dropdown box.

I'm getting the JSON just fine from the PHP file. It looks like this:

```
[{"state":"AL"},{"state":"AK"},{"state":"AZ"},{"state":"AR"}]
```

I can see in the response in developer tools that it's coming over fine. However, when I look at the JSON, line 1 is empty and everything is on line 2. Not sure if that's a problem or not.

On the HTML side, here's what I've got:

```
<select id="myselect"></select>
```

and

```
 $.getJSON('state_get.php', function(data) {               
   $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    $('#myselect').append("<option>"+key.text+"</option>");
})
 });
```

What I get in my dropdowns are a bunch of options with "undefined". There appear to be one for each JSON value, so something's party right, but not all the way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `$('#myselect').append("<option>"+key.state+"</option>");`

Answer (score 3):

The first argument to each callback is the index, second is the value also the key to the property is `State` not `text`

```
$.getJSON('state_get.php', function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        $('#myselect').append("<option>" + val.state + "</option>");
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You object has property `state`, not `text`

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
  $('#myselect').append("<option>" + val.state + "</option>");
});
```

Comment: You've got an extra .append in your answer, but it worked after that. This was new learning for me, as I didn't know how to use properties correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First argument of `$.each` when looping an array is `index`, the second is the element of the array

Try

```
$('#myselect').append("<option>"+val.state+"</option>");
```

Each of the objects in your array would be an element

reference [**jQuery.each() API Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$('#myselect').append("<option>"+val.state+"</option>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets have dropdown like below

```
<select id="myselect" name="stateList" class="state-list ></select>
```

You can append your value like this

```
var stateSelector = $('select.state-list'); 
var option = $("<option value=''></option>"); 

$.each(data, function(key, val) {
option = $("<option value='" + val.state + "'>" + val.state + "</option>"); 
stateSelector.append(option);           
});
```

`$('.state-list').selectpicker('refresh');` // you can refresh your dropdown if required